# Using Google Places library in native android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Its mentioned in the documentation - 
(https://developers.google.com/places/uplift)
*If you are developing a web based application that only needs to search for places, and is not submitting new places or Place Bumps, you should use the Places library of the Maps API rather than using the Places API web service. The Places library assigns a quota to each end user rather than to each key. This means that your available quota increases with your user base rather than being capped at a fixed amount*

I am developing an android native app which uses Places API for place searches only. However reading the above, can I implement Places library of the Maps API in my android application so that I can get increased quota? Can this be done using Google Maps V2? Or is this applicable for Google Maps Javascript API v3 only?

Comment: Sorry..it has been almost a year..But did you fount out answer to your question? It would be great if you could share some insights.. Thanks!